# Characteristic polynomials of T-invariant subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohxsZ.png) How do I show that product of characteristics polynomial of T-invariant sub spaces is same as that of T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Pick a basis $\gamma_1$ for $W_1$ and a basis $\gamma_2$ for $W_2$. Then, $\beta = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ is a basis for $V$ (why?) and, because the subspaces are $T$-invariant, the matrix representation of $T$ in this basis $\beta$ is a block matrix of the form
$$[T]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B\end{pmatrix}.$$